# What is the purpose of following an ABI for calls local to the module? Where is it even enforced?

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler-construction, x86-64, abi

I understand that an ABI is a non-language-specific construct that defines things such as the way that data is passed from one function to another. It is the job of the compiler to adhere to such ABIs. I also understand how an ABI may be useful for inter-modular calls, that is, calling into a .dll for example, as if we did not have a well-defined calling convention, there would be no reliable way to pass the data on.

Where I become lost is the purpose of such a thing for functions that have **no external references**. Couldn't the compiler just create its own arbitrary calling convention for each function? I have seen compilers produce strange, modified versions of existing calling conventions. To further the confusion, the [official documentation for the x64 calling convention](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170) often uses very rigid language, for example:

> There's a strict one-to-one correspondence between a function call's
> arguments and the registers used for those arguments.

Yet, at least in x86 calling conventions such as __thiscall, I have seen their conventions violated by compilers in functions with **no external references**. So, why do these conventions even exist for functions with no external references, and what happens when we violate them in that case?

Comment: It's *not* strictly enforced; compilers could in theory be more aggressive than most  currently are about inventing custom calling conventions, but compilers *do* already do some inter-procedural analysis e.g. taking advantage of a function not clobbering some registers that the ABI says are call-clobbered.  But usually if GCC wants to do constant-propagation for some but not all args, it'll make a `.clone.constprop...` version of a function and still keep the main version.

Comment: The operating system needs to understand what the program is doing, even for intra-module calls, because the operating system may need to do things like run a signal handler or unwind the stack due to an exception. You can still make up custom calling conventions provided the parts the operating system cares about are still maintained.

Comment: Many of the use cases where this would help are solved even more effectively by just inlining the function, which compilers already know how to do.  So the extra gains from allowing custom calling conventions might not be that great, and thus this optimization might not be a high priority for compilers to implement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no strict requirement for a compiler to follow the ABI for functions with no external references it is free to do as it chooses but often the gain from violating the ABI is only marginal which makes the optimization not worth the effort to implement.